# Запятая и тире / тире / запятая

Tags: пунктуация

Правильны какие варианты?

> Есть, как всем известно, по-моему интересные, выражения *в отсутствие* и *в присутствии* — довольно похожих, но, как видно, отличающихся по последней гласной, которую надо запомнить.

> Есть, как всем известно, по-моему интересные, выражения *в отсутствие* и *в присутствии*, довольно похожих, но, как видно, отличающихся по последней гласной, которую надо запомнить.

> Есть, как всем известно, по-моему интересные, выражения *в отсутствие* и *в присутствии*, — довольно похожих, но, как видно, отличающихся по последней гласной, которую надо запомнить.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Предлагается решение **NEW** :

*Есть — / **как всем известно, по-моему интересные,** /  —  выражения    «в отсутствие и в присутствии»,  // — **довольно похожие, но, как видно, отличающиеся** по последней гласной, которую надо запомнить.*

**Пояснение**

1. Использована **вставка**: обособление двумя тире, запятая после первого тире.
2. Вместо запятой поставлен **ЕДИНЫЙ ЗНАК** "запятая и тире" в связи со значительной **распространенностью** обособленного оборота. Это результат **анализа** структуры и семантики предложения.

Выбор знаков соответствует **произношению:** подчеркнутая пауза перед обособленным оборотом.

К тому же вторая часть предложения может являться  **отдельным сообщением** (по смыслу, семантике и грамматике): ***Эти** выражения  довольно похожи, но, как видно, отличаются по последней гласной, которую надо запомнить.*

**ВЫВОД**

Не следует подходить к решению задачи только с точки зрения **формальных правил**, но нужно учитывать все **принципы** пунктуации. Предложение должно легко **читаться и пониматься**.

Comment: А запятая и тире ставится как единый знак, когда обособленный оборот сольно распространен?

Comment: Это я его предлагаю использовать единый знак при решении задачи. А объяснение можно подобрать. Например:  при значительной распространенности оборота можно поставить ДОПОЛНИТЕЛЬНОЕ тире.  А вот прочитать предложение, где подряд идут восемь и более запятых весьма затруднительно. При этом  надо все-таки выделить вставку (не включать ее в основное сообщение) а вот два тематических слова как раз в него включить и т.д.

Comment: Решение задач методом БЛОКОВ делается для сложных предложений, но почему бы не использовать подобный анализ и для предложений осложнённых.   Граница двух сообщений фактически находится перед определительным оборотом. Все-таки правила должны подчиняться смыслу, а не наоборот.

Answer (score 0):

Нехорошо мне видится предложение без двоеточия/тире после *выражения*. Поэтому предлагаю варианты:

***Есть, как всем известно, по-моему интересные, выражения: «в отсутствие» и «в присутствии», довольно похожие, но, как видно, отличающиеся по последней гласной, которую надо запомнить***;

***Есть, как всем известно, по-моему интересные, выражения — «в отсутствие» и «в присутствии», — довольно похожие, но, как видно, отличающиеся по последней гласной, которую надо запомнить***.

В первом варианте есть обобщающее слово, а дальше — однородный ряд. Но однородный ряд **не завершается тире, это тире поглощает запятая**. О поглощеннии запятой тире в [справочнике Розенталя, пункт 8](http://old-rozental.ru/punctuatio.php?sid=103).

А во втором варианте **пояснительный оборот**, перед вторым тире которого ставится запятая, т. к. ее требует вторая часть предложения.

---

А слово *похожих* лучше заменить на *похожие (выражения)*.

Изменено.

*Отличающихся* тоже надо бы заменить на *отличающиеся*.

Comment: @АлександрСтрелец Спасибо, исправил.

Comment: *Отличающи**е**ся* ещё бы надо.

Comment: Спасибо, не заметил.